# Python MasterMind Can't get program to return amount of right digits in wrong place

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to make a numeric list based mastermind game. This is how my program looks as of now.

I have a function so that if a the numbers in the two lists are equal at the same index (trulycorrect) the function returns the amount of numbers in the correct place.

My problem is that i can't figure out a function that returns the amount of number that are on the wrong index but exist in both lists. That acounts for the same number accuring in the user guess.

zExample 1: If my generated list = [3,1,3,3] and the user guesses [3,3,3,3]
the output should be.
3 in the right place 0 in the wrong place 
But i get. 
3 in the right place 1 in the wrong place.

Example 2: If my generated list = [8,1,1,1] and the user guesses [8,8,8,8]
the output should be.
1 in the right place 0 in the wrong place 
But i get. 
1 in the right place 3 in the wrong place.

Hope you understand what i mean. PS i'm a python newbie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your `right_inwrongplace` function. You need to make sure you are ignoring all correct guesses before counting the guesses which are right but in the wrong place. You can do it by first removing the correct guesses from the list:

```
def right_inwrongplace(userGuess, number):
    # Create a list of Boolean values representing correct guesses.
    # for exemple: if numbers = [1,2,3,4] and guess = [1,2,9,9], correct_places will be [True,True,False,False]
    correct_places = [True if v == number[i] else False for i, v in enumerate(userGuess)]
    # create a list with only the incorrect guesses.
    g = [v for  i, v in enumerate(userGuess) if not correct_places[i]]
    # create a list with the numbers which weren't guessed correctly.
    n = [v for  i, v in enumerate(number) if not correct_places[i]]
    #return the amount of guesses that are correct but in the wrong place. (the numbers that are in both lists) 
    return len([i for i in g if i in n])
```

Comment: Hi could you comment the code on what's happening since i'm new to python i have a hard time following

Comment: @LinusRiesle-palgan added some comments, hope it helps.